# Rename several columns with year labels without repeating logic

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, rename

I have several columns in my dataframe that are unnamed except for a number. In this case, the columns are numbered 50 to 59. I want to rename the columns with year labels, i.e. column 50 would be renamed to '2006', column 51 renamed to '2007', and so forth.

I have the following code to rename the columns, which works, but it seems overly repetitive, in terms of how much typing I have to do:

```
GDP.rename(columns={50:'2006', 51:'2007', 52:'2008', 53:'2009',54:'2010', 55:'2011', 56:'2012', 57:'2013', 58:'2014', 59:'2015'}, inplace=True)
```

Is there a way to use the `.rename()` method in a less verbose way

I feel I should be able to pass in a range of columns, such as [49:60] and a range of years [2006:2015] into the `.rename()` method to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have a couple of options.

**Option 1**

Use a dictionary comprehension:

```
GDP.rename(columns={i: str(1956+i) for i in range(50, 60)}, inplace=True)
```

**Option 2**

Use a custom function. This can be an anonymous `lambda`:

```
GDP.rename(columns=lambda x: str(1956+x) if isinstance(x, int) else x, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you. The lambda option is what I was going for cuz it's what I'm learning in my data science course. However, the dictionary comprehension is the more easily understandable option for me cuz I'm still green when it comes to using lambdas. Using my specific example, how do I construct the custom function in the lambda? That is, what goes into 'x'?

Comment: Or, wait a minute . . .are you saying 'x' is the function in that lambda? I.e. Look for column names that are integers and then change them to be strings where 1956 is added to each integer in the column name, resulting in the correct year label?

Comment: Never mind. I understand it now. Thank you again for the speedy response and assistance! Many thanks and most appreciated!